# Count number of times value appears in particular column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

This has probably been asked before, but I'm unable to make my way through the myriad of search results.

Given a non-normalized MySQL table, what is the most optimized query to count the number of times each distinct value of column x was used?

e.g. Given a table containing

```
mike
mary
mike
```

Return results like:

```
mike 2
mary 1
```

From the MySQL documentation, it would seem that `count` is an aggregate function that can be used with `GROUP BY`, but it's not doing what I want (it's returning the total number of rows in the `GROUP BY`, not the number of appearances for each row. i.e. this does not work `SELECT count(email) as c FROM orders GROUP BY email`

Comment: `i.e. this does not work` --- explain it in details please. "Doesn't work" is not helpful at all

Comment: Thanks. Will do I don't know what came over me when I asked it.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
select email, count(*) as c FROM orders GROUP BY email
```

Comment: Apparently I had misread the results. Including the "email" in there made it clearer what data I was seeing. There really was nothing wrong with the query I have in my post. Thanks.

Comment: order is a good ideia, so my contribuition: select email, count(*) as c FROM orders GROUP BY email ORDER BY c DESC;

Answer (score 26):

```
SELECT column_name, COUNT(column_name)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Group by function.

What the group by function does is pretuty much grouping the similar value for a given field. You can then show the number of number of time that this value was groupped using the COUNT function.

[MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/group-by-functions.html)

You can also use the group by function with a good number of other function define by MySQL (see the above link).

```
mysql> SELECT student_name, AVG(test_score)
    ->        FROM student
    ->        GROUP BY student_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, count(*) from table group by name;
```

i think should do it