# Count number of times 2 values appear at the same time in two columns

Tags: sql, ssms

Was able to use:
[Count number of times value appears in particular column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199950/count-number-of-times-value-appears-in-particular-column-in-mysql)

to write:

```
select 
  ScheduleId,count(*) as s, 
  EmployeeId,count(*) as e 
  from Schedules
  group by ScheduleId, EmployeeId
```

which returns something like so:

```
ScheduleId   p       EmployeeId   e
1            1       24242        1
2            1       83928        1
3            1       93829        1
4            2       84993        2
5            1       43434        1
```

I only want to show the records that have count on both ScheduleId   and employeeId > 1
so only show

```
4            2       84993        2
```

Iv tried to include this with the query
where p.count(*) > 1 etc..

but I cant seem to get it.

Any help please?

Comment: WHERE filters results before they’re aggregated. HAVING filters results after they’re aggregated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much there. You just need to filter your results:

```sql
SELECT
    ScheduleId, COUNT(*) as s,
    EmployeeId, COUNT(*) as e
FROM
    Schedules
GROUP BY
    ScheduleId, EmployeeId
HAVING
    COUNT(ScheduleId) > 1 AND COUNT(EmployeeId) > 1
```